# inline-block on a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

After scrolling through different answers from previous stack overflow questions - I came across a navigation bar code similar to this. Works fine.

I understand by using inline-block on .ulTest li it's essentially making the navigation bar horizontal. However I can't really grasp why it has inline-block on .ulTest li a. I've tried adding/removing it, and from removing it the navigation bar height becomes smaller. Can anyone explain to me what this line is actually doing and how its effecting the page? thanks :)

```
.ulTest
{
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.ulTest li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.ulTest li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because an anchor element would then only be inline, the browser default, and its height would only be the height of the surrounding line box. By making it block, you can make the height of that element the same size as the surrounding parent element while keeping them all in a row as in "inline".

So, take your html and css and put them together. Use your developer tools and look at the size of the anchor element as inline versus inline-block and you'll notice the difference. As block level, you can adjust height and margin and padding in ways you can't with inline.

Comment: the difference is 1309 * 51 and 1309 * 21 - but I'm still not quite understanding it. Any resources/links you could recommend that explains it further?